# Change DWARF elf format in IAR ARM V8 compiler

Tags: c, elf, iar, dwarf

In our development, we switched from IAR ARM V7.40 to IAR ARM V8.40

We are using the python package `pyelftools` for postprocessing of the debug information. Unfortunately, this seems to be broken now, as the V8-compiler seems to use DWARF4 syntax, which is not fully covered by pyelftools. The V7-compiler used DWARF3 which was fine.

Is there any compiler option for IAR V8 to change DWARF format? In the *IAR C/C++ Development Guide*, I only find the `--debug, -r` option to enable debug information, but no further fine tunings (e.g. like `-gdwarf-3` option for the arm-clang compiler).

Comment: As per documantaion this script does not fully support Dwarf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a hidden compiler option `--no_dwarf4` which disables DWARF4. This works fine for our problem.

Unfortunately, this compiler option is neither documented in the *IAR C/C++ Development Guide* nor listed in the command line help (`$ iccarm --help`) for the compiler.